# Is there any benefit to having more than 5 orb enhance awakenings on your team?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

Orb enhance awakenings give a 20% chance for orbs of that color (from skyfall, not orb change) to be enhanced. Once you have 5 such awakenings, all orbs of that color will be enhanced, and orbs can't be double-enhanced or anything, so it seems like there wouldn't be any benefit to having additional orb enhance awakenings (of the same color).

I've seen some conversations on Reddit & PADX that seemed to imply that additional orb enhance awakenings of the same color increased the enhance bonus once the 100% chance for enhancement was reached, but I haven't been able to find anything clearly stating that in the game or the release notes.

Please note that I am aware of but not interested in the case when one of my cards is bound. I know having additional awakenings can keep my chance for enhanced orbs at 100% despite a card with an awakening being bound.

Does adding a 6th orb enhance awakening of a given color increase your damage with that color, or is the awakening a waste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, additional orb enhance awakenings provide a benefit.**

From the [7.2.2 patch notes](https://www.facebook.com/notes/puzzle-dragons-north-america-gungho/722-patch-notes/955612234467369/?_fb_noscript=1):

> *Both appearance and attack power of Enhanced Orbs increase with each additional active Enhanced Orb Awoken Skill of the matching attribute.

So even once you have the 5 awakenings for a 100% chance that orbs of that color (from skyfall) will be enhanced, additional awakenings continue to increase the damage done by enhanced orbs.